# java 6 web services share domain specific classes between server and client

Tags: java, web-services, wsimport, java-web-start

**Context:**  
Considering below defined Engine class being parameter of some webservice method. As we have both server and client in java we may have some benefits (???) in sharing Engine class between server and client ( i.e we may put in a common jar file to be added to both client and server classpath )

Some benefits would be :

1. we keep specific operations like 'brushEngine' in same place

   build is faster as we do not need in our case to generate java code for client classes but to use them from the server build)

   if we later change server implementation for 'brushEngine' this is reflected automatically in client .

**Questions:**

- How to share below detailed Engine class using java 6 tools ( i.e wsimport , wsgen etc )?

  Is there other tools for java that can achieve this sharing ?

  Is sharing a case that java 6 web services support is missing ?

  Can this case be reduced to other web service usage patterns?

Thanks.

**Code:**

```
public class Engine {

   private String engineData;

   public String getData(){
        return data;
   }

   public setData(String value){
        this.data = value;
   } 

   public void brushEngine(){
        engineData = "BrushedEngine"+engineData; 

   } 

}
```

Comment: Why does this smell like homework to me?

Comment: sorry to say but is not homework, looks like the smell has tricked you.

Comment: If you have by miracle any tech specific comment about how to do the sharing please post it . Thanks.

Comment: After so many months there is no solution to this. therefore this has very small particles of homework smell. Please seek some professional smell care.